# Stack Image Slider Gallery in Android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, image-gallery, arcore

I have been watching a video and fascinated by a catalog gallery, How can I make image gallery shown in the video at 1:04, or any keyword to search library for it

Thanks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkmkNZ7O1NA